# How To Get Value and Set Name From Dynamic Form

Tags: php, forms

Maybe the title  made confused. But I have a case like this,

I have a form that contains some input text (textbox). But this input is depend on my database.

```
<label class="strong"><?php echo $rowexp['mexpense_name']; ?></label>
<input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Expense <?php echo $rowexp['mexpense_name']; ?>" name="" />
```

Here's my database for that input text:

```
tbl_mexpensive -> mexpensive_id, mexpensive_name
tbl_expensive -> expensive id, expensive_year
tbl_texpensive -> mexpensive_id, expensive_id
```

So the number of textfield will be same as much as the data at tbl_mexpensive and the POST page will set to tbl_texpensive.

For example, if mexpensive got 3 value then:
`[textbox1] [textbox2] [textbox3]
If i click submit
It return to POST page and get the value each of the textbox
BUT the query is like this: insert into texpensive (exp_id, mexp_id) VALUE (exp_id, XXX)`

From above, my question is, how to get the value at the POST page (XXX)? I mean, what name should I give to that input text? I have try an array but it's not work properly. I try give it name as the table value, still no result because it's a dynamic textbox.

Sorry for my bad English.

--EDIT

My POST PAGE

```html
$asal = $_POST['asal'];
 $unit = $_POST['unit'];
 $tahun = $_POST['tahun'];
 $querydata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM m_mainexpense WHERE mexpense_status=1");
 
 $last = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_expense");
 $getlast = mysql_fetch_array($last);
 $nom = (int)$getlast['expense_id'] + 1;
 while($rowdata = mysql_fetch_array($querydata))
 {
  if(isset($_POST[mexpense_name]))
  {
            //actually don't know what to do in here
   $arr = $_POST[mexpense_name];
   $query = "INSERT INTO t_expense (texp_mext, texp_exp) VALUES ('$arr','$nom')";
  }
 }
 
 $query = "INSERT INTO m_expense(expense_unit, expense_school, expense_year, expense_type, expense_status) 
    VALUES ('$unit', '$asal', '$tahun', 1)";
 if(mysql_query($query))
 {
  
  echo "<script>
        alert('Penambahan Data Sukses');
        window.location.href='return_index.php';
     </script>";
  echo '<noscript>
  Please Enable Your JavaScript.
  <a href="welcome.php">Main Menu</a>
  </noscript>';
  die();
 }
```

Comment: Its bit hard to understand, please edit this with your post action.

Comment: thanks for reply. Post action added..

Comment: Why the name of the input field is blank ?

Comment: Hello, because I don't know what to type... Already try an array (name[]) still no idea what to do... I am now try multidimension array (still trying but no result)

Comment: Try it with <input type="text" name="item[0][name]" /> and try dumping post variable in POST page.

Comment: hello, its ouput: `array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [1]=> string(4) "2000" [2]=> string(5) "50000" [3]=> string(4) "2000" [4]=> string(4) "2000" } }` my code is : `name="item[0][<?php echo $rowexp['mexpense_id']; ?>]"`

Comment: Hi TNC, You give me clue... Now it's solved... Thanks....

Comment: Glad to hear from you. You solved it by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using key($array) and get the value by foreach function. And return it to database. Finally it solved....